# At what point do the Input Parameters of a WCF Workflow Service get instantiated/set?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, workflow, parameter-passing, xoml

I have a very simple XOML file with a single Code Activity inside the `ReceiveActivity` Handler.

The ReceiveActivity is mapped to an Interface called `IRulesEngineService` wih a single method on it.

```
void DoWork(int i);
```

the input parameter on the interface method is mapped to a property on the Xoml called `I`

[image: Simple Workflow / Simple Input Parameter]

I'm now trying to attempt to step into the Workflow Life Cycle at a point:

- just before the first (and in this case only) Code Activity gets executed
- just after the `i` parameter has been assigned to `I` on my Workflow.

I've tried overriding all the various methods and events on the XOML but in all cases `I` is always zero in all the events and overrides I've tried. And then is correctly set to the passed in Parameter within the first Code Activity. e.g. Imagine I passed in `8` to the ClientSide DoWork call.

```
    public int I {get; set;}

    protected override void Initialize(System.IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        I = I*10; //I is still 0
        base.Initialize(provider);
        I = I * 10; //I is still 0
    }

    //Event on Xoml Designer
    private void Pinnacle_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        I = I * 10; //I is still 0
    }

    //Event on Xoml Designer
    private void receiveActivity1_OperationValidation(object sender, OperationValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        I = I * 10; //I is still 0
    }

    protected override void OnActivityExecutionContextLoad(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        I = I * 10; //I is still 0
        base.OnActivityExecutionContextLoad(provider);
        I = I * 10; //I is still 0
    }

    private void codeActivity1_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess.WriteToDummyData(ConnectionString, "Pinnacle From Code Activity " + I);
        //I is now magically '8' what the heck set this?
    }
```

Anyone got any ideas on where in the Workflow Lifecycle the instantiating/binding/setting of these parameters occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the .NET framework source code, it's not possible to access your data inputs within the code activity before the execution. in the ReceiveActivity class in the System.Workflow.Activities namespace there's a exact point where the inputs are populated. I've taken the class source from [this link](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/cdf/src/NetFx35/System@WorkflowServices/System/Workflow/Activities/ReceiveActivity@cs/1305376/ReceiveActivity@cs)

See the image below:

[image: ExecuteActivity Method]

As you can see in the picture inputs are populated at this point:

```
this.OperationHelper.PopulateInputs(this, requestContext.Inputs);
```

The instruction above is called just before the ReceiveActivity class executes the activity. At this stage I don't think there's a public event that can be subscribed to manipulate your data before your codeActivity1_ExecuteCode gets executed.

Hope it helps.